# Changing the text of a twitter bootstrap modal dynamically

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a twitter bootstrap modal on a page and it works pretty well. However, sometimes I want to change its caption and body dynamically while it's being shown.

How do I do that?

```
    function showModal(){
      $("#ajaxModal").modal({keyboard: false, show: true, backdrop: 'static'});
    }

    function hideModal(){
      $("#ajaxModal").modal('hide');
    }


   ///.............
   showModal();
   //.........
   hideModal();
```

Comment: why not show us wat you are working with , so that we can help you better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had worked on same scenario..here is the example may be it works for you..

This is just sample scenario.. i had find the element 



 in the modal **myModal** and passed my value, i had passed dynamically **'alertMsg'**

```
$('#myModal').find('p').html('<span style="color:#4F2817;">'+alertMsg+'</span>');
```